# Fast algorithm for line removing

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I am developing a pipeline for recognising scaned financial reports. They contains a lot of straight lines in headers and tables, so I need to remove straight lines in pupose of segmentation. 
Here is an example of report's header: [image]

And this is result of applying of scharr filter:
[image]
This step allow me not to matter about thickness of straight line, but I don't know what to do in the next step. I tried probabilistic_hough_line, but find it too time consuming and unneffective in my case. Collegues, do you have any idea which may be halpfull for me?